# Android EditText isSelectAll() method?

Tags: android, android-edittext

EditText's selectAll() helps selecting all the text of the widget. Now, my question is:  "Is it possible to check whether all the text of the EditText has been selected?". In technical terms, I would like to implement isSelectAll() method on EditText. How is it possible?

Thanks in advance for your valuable answers and suggestions.

~
PCoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
boolean isSelectAll() {
    return ((editText.getSelectionStart() == 0) && (editText.getSelectionEnd() == editText.getText().length()));
}
```